# class method where self if used within a block

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, objective-c-blocks, weak-references

I've got a class method that uses `dispatch_once` to create a static object. Inside the `dispatch_once` block I use `[self class]` and was wondering if I need to use a weak reference to `self` to avoid a retain cycle?

```
+ (NSArray *)accountNames{
    static NSArray *names = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t predicate;
    dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{
        names = [[[self class] accounts] allKeys];
        names = [names sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    });
    return names;
}
```

If I use a weak reference to `self` I get a warning:

```
+ (NSArray *)accountNames{
    static NSArray *names = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t predicate;
    __weak TUAccount *wself = self;
    dispatch_once(&predicate, ^{
        names = [[[wself class] accounts] allKeys];
        names = [names sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    });
    return names;
}
```

**Incompatible pointer types initializing 'TUAccount *__weak' with an expression of type 'const Class'**

Because I get a warning I don't think I need to use a weak reference to `self` in this case but I wanted to see what you guys thought.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no reason to worry about a retain cycle here, because it's meaningless to retain or release a class object -- retain and release simply have no effect.

Your attempt at making a weak reference is wrong, because you are taking a class object `self` and trying to cast it to an *instance* of `TUAccount`. The two are completely different things.

Also, you can simplify:

```
names = [[[self class] accounts] allKeys];
```

Since self is already a class, [self class] == self, so do this instead:

```
names = [[self accounts] allKeys];
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure why but using `self` for some class methods doesn't work which is why I use `[self class]` to call all class methods.

Comment: Any class methods in particular -- yours, or ones in Apple's frameworks? And what do you mean by "doesn't work"? There's probably a reason.

Comment: Ok it's based on where the method is called from. For the `accounts` class method for instance, which is my own class method. I can call it by `[self accounts]` from other class methods but have to use `[[self class] accounts]` in instance methods. So you're right in the example code above it could just be `[self accounts]`.

Comment: That's exactly how it's supposed to work! In a class method, `self` is the class. In an instance method, `self` is the instance, and `[self class]` is the class.

Comment: I never made that distinction before on when to use one or the other and just always used `[self class]` for both, thanks :)

Comment: @keegan3d: well, you should make that distinction because they are calling two different methods: calling `class` on a class object calls `+class` (since `+class` exists, it overrides `-class` for class objects), which just returns the thing it is called on. calling `class` on a non-class object calls `-class`, which returns the class of the object. You can see that they are two different methods in the documentation.

Comment: @newacct in my instance methods is it alright to use `[self class]` or should I use the full class name? Is calling `[[self class] accounts]` the same as `[TUAccount accounts]` in an instance method?

Comment: @keegan3d: No, they are not the same. `[self class]` returns the actual class of the object, which could be a subclass of `TUAccount` that inherited this method. In general, you should use `[self class]` because (1) it is portable, not requiring you to hard-code the class; but more importantly (2) it allows you to use the correct behavior for subclasses, because subclasses might have overridden some methods to behave differently. It allows you to do things like `[[self class] alloc]` to create another object of the same class.

Comment: @newacct cool, glad to hear the portable version is the way to go! Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

I have checked one more time iOS SDK Docs and found next:

> Objective-C Objects
>
> In a manually reference-counted environment, local variables used within the block are retained when the block is copied. Use of instance variables within the block will cause the object itself to be retained. If you wish to override this behavior for a particular object variable, you can mark it with the __block storage type modifier.
>
> If you are using ARC, object variables are retained and released automatically as the block is copied and later released.
>
> - Note: In a garbage-collected environment, if you apply both __weak and __block modifiers to a variable, then the block will not ensure that it is kept alive.
>
> If you use a block within the implementation of a method, the rules for memory management of object instance variables are more subtle:
>
> - If you access an instance variable by reference, self is retained;
> - If you access an instance variable by value, the variable is retained.

The following examples illustrate the two different situations:

```
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    // instanceVariable is used by reference, self is retained
    doSomethingWithObject(instanceVariable);
});


id localVariable = instanceVariable;
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    // localVariable is used by value, localVariable is retained (not self)
    doSomethingWithObject(localVariable);
});
```

Conclusion: I assume that there is no problem with using `self` in block. It will be retained and after execution released.

Moreover, you are not storing block in memory and using it directly. So it is copied to the heap, executed and pushed from it. I don't see any retain cycles.

Hope I am right!

Comment: `id` is a pointer, so in the second situation, does `localVariable` still refer to the same object as `instanceVariable`?

Comment: @Elliot If you set new value to `instanceVariable` then `localVariable` will not be updated. If `instanceVariable` is mutable and is changed then `localVariable` will reference the same value.